# 404 - Projeto Java EE Maven com Spring retorna 404

Tags: java, mvc, spring, tomcat, maven

Estou tendo problemas com a configuração do Spring do meu projeto Maven, no qual para testar se estava tudo funcionando, um simples olá mundo não funcionou e aparentemente não há erros explícitos, alguém por favor me salva aí !

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>yum-poc</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name> Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping> 
  <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
  <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

spring-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.poc.yum.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

OlaMundoController

```
package br.com.poc.yum.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class OlaMundoController {
    @RequestMapping("/olaMundo")
    public String olaMundo() {
        System.out.println("Esta merda deu certo");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

log do TomCat

```
out 02, 2018 1:12:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:yum-poc' did not find a matching property.
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          Sep 4 2018 22:13:41 UTC
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server number:         9.0.12.0
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Windows 10
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            10.0
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          amd64
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-b13
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\wtpwebapps
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\endorsed
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.17] using APR version [1.6.3].
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
out 02, 2018 1:12:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
out 02, 2018 1:12:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFORMAÇÕES: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018]
out 02, 2018 1:12:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
out 02, 2018 1:12:24 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
out 02, 2018 1:12:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
out 02, 2018 1:12:24 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
out 02, 2018 1:12:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 2885 ms
out 02, 2018 1:12:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service [Catalina]
out 02, 2018 1:12:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
out 02, 2018 1:12:37 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
out 02, 2018 1:12:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
out 02, 2018 1:12:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet'
out 02, 2018 1:12:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFORMAÇÕES: FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet': initialization started
out 02, 2018 1:12:38 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFORMAÇÕES: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet-servlet': startup date [Tue Oct 02 13:12:38 BRT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
out 02, 2018 1:12:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFORMAÇÕES: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml]
out 02, 2018 1:12:40 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFORMAÇÕES: Mapped "{[/olaMundo]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.poc.yum.controller.OlaMundoController.olaMundo()
out 02, 2018 1:12:40 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFORMAÇÕES: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet-servlet': startup date [Tue Oct 02 13:12:38 BRT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
out 02, 2018 1:12:41 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFORMAÇÕES: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet-servlet': startup date [Tue Oct 02 13:12:38 BRT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
out 02, 2018 1:12:41 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFORMAÇÕES: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0'
out 02, 2018 1:12:41 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFORMAÇÕES: FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet': initialization completed in 3265 ms
out 02, 2018 1:12:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\docs]
out 02, 2018 1:12:50 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
out 02, 2018 1:12:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\docs] has finished in [8,977] ms
out 02, 2018 1:12:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\examples]
out 02, 2018 1:12:59 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
out 02, 2018 1:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
out 02, 2018 1:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
out 02, 2018 1:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@15a55f69')
out 02, 2018 1:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\examples] has finished in [8,799] ms
out 02, 2018 1:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\host-manager]
out 02, 2018 1:13:06 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
out 02, 2018 1:13:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [7,283] ms
out 02, 2018 1:13:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\manager]
out 02, 2018 1:13:13 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
out 02, 2018 1:13:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\manager] has finished in [7,190] ms
out 02, 2018 1:13:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\ROOT]
out 02, 2018 1:13:21 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
out 02, 2018 1:13:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [7,558] ms
out 02, 2018 1:13:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
out 02, 2018 1:13:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
out 02, 2018 1:13:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 56626 ms
```

Algumas soluções foram testadas como dar clean através do server, do Maven e do próprio projeto, também nenhum desses funcionou, então estou meio perdido.

Comment: Qual url você está tentando acessar para testar o teu Olá Mundo?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/olaMundo

Answer (score 0):

Opa, creio que o problema seja a configuração no seu spring-context.xml:

```
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
```

Nesse caso, você está fazendo com que qualquer url seja mapeada para uma .jsp na sua pasta 
WEB-INF/views. Como essa jsp não deve existir (/WEB-INF/views/olaMundo.jsp), você vai receber o http status code 404 mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado Rodrigo, a página da qual estou retornando é a index, que se encontra na views já, porém fazendo a busca dessa página, simplesmente soa como se não existisse.

Comment: Para visualizar a index, você precisaria bater na url http://localhost:8080/index não?

Comment: Não, pois mapeei a requisição no request mapping para funcionar através da /olaMundo, mas retorno através da string o nome da página que desejo, que no caso é a index